# What is the difference between LUN and array ? Arent they same?

Tags: lun

Please clarify what do we mean by LUN and Array ? and if they are similar in meaning?.

The confusion is because both are presented to specific servers by the combination of different Hard disks or individual Hard disk ( correct me if am worng )

Answer (score 8):

A LUN (Logical Unit Number) is a number used to uniquely identify *any device* that is attached to a SCSI device chain, or anything that emulates a SCSI device chain.

Some devices that could be attached to a device chain and would be assigned a LUN include:

- A single hard disk.
- An array of hard disks.
- A tape drive.
- A CD-ROM drive.

It's important to remember that while SCSI is mostly deprecated today, many operating systems and devices emulate SCSI-like bahavior.  This includes SAN technologies like iSCSI and Fiber Channel, which you may be referring to here.

Comment: Great answer Kyle but if you don't mind I'd like to state in Fisher Price terms that in general a LUN is a bit of disk space on an array that's presented to one or more clients.

Comment: SCSI is *not* deprecated. SCSI is a command set that is still very alive. Yes, the old *parallel* SCSI interconnect is on death's door, but SAS, FC, iSCSI, etc. are all technologies that use the SCSI command set that aren't going away any time soon.

Comment: @ErikA - +1 Good point.